# nodejs sending file to client hangs until server is killed

Tags: node.js, http, file-transfer

I am trying to send a csv file to the client.

When I do this, the download begins, but hangs on "starting...." and says it is transmitting at 0B/s.

When I kill the server, the file is transmitted and is all there.

What's causing this?

```
app.get('/weather_log.csv', function(req, res){
  console.log('sending weather log')
  filePath = 'weather_log.csv'
  var file = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'binary');
  console.log(typeof(file))
  res.setHeader('Content-Length', fs.statSync(filePath));
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', "attachment;filename=" + filePath);
  res.write(file, 'binary');
  res.end();
})
```

My guess is that res.end() is not firing or that the client doesn't realise that the file transfer is not complete for some other reason.

Comment: Have you tried using res.download(filePath) instead of reading the file manually and setting headers?

Comment: Big File?  Did you try an async call?

Comment: Should the file encoding be 'binary'?
Is the file path correct?
What if you `fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(res)`?

Comment: It's a tiny file, less than a kB. I will try that a0js but I'd still like to know why this isnt working. The file path is correct, the file successfully transfers after I manually kill the server which would not happen if I was specifying a nonexistent file.

Comment: I don't think `res.setHeader('Content-Length', fs.statSync(filePath));` is going to do anything useful.  Try `res.setHeader('Content-Length', fs.statSync(filePath).size.toString());` or, better, `res.setHeader('Content-Length', file.length.toString());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per a0js, the answer was to use res.download(filePath).